# 2003 Suzuki Katana 600 shuts off after running for 10–20 seconds

Tags: engine, motorcycle, suzuki, stall, katana

My 2003 Suzuki Katana GSX600F shuts off after ten to twenty seconds after start. It doesn't spit and sputter, it just shuts down. I have loosened the bowl screws while it's running and confirmed that there is fuel there. The bike was sat in storage for six years because of this. I got it out yesterday and the problem persists. How should I proceed with the diagnosis?

Comment: Does it start again immediately? What happens if you hold the revs higher? Has it been serviced (Fuel and air intake filters in particular)? Also, are you using fresh fuel?

Comment: ^this pretty much sums up all the checks you need to do.